# Accessing the child of an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need help in accessing a class using jQuery but not sure how can I do it. Below is my html structure:

```
<div class='a'>
    <div class='child'>
    <input type='text'/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='b'>
    <div class='child'>
    <input type='text'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to access 'child' of the div having class 'a' but not 'b'. Also can I access input of class a in this scenario?

Comment: $('.a :input') ... http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $child = $("div.a .child");//Child of div with class a

$child.find("input");//This will give you input within div with class child

//OR you can use this also    

var $input = $("div.a input");//input of div with class a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//the child
$(".a .child");

//the input    
$(".a input");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Select all element with class child inside an element with class a
$('.a .child');

// Select all input elements inside all elements with class a
$('.a input');
```